# Angular, behavior subject, change data in one component, make changes in another component

Tags: angular

I have two components(no relationship) and one service.

on click of comp1
I need to make some Boolean value true in comp1 and comp2.

then again on click from comp1,  I need to make boolean value true in comp2.
I tried this thing with behavior subject but its not catching the changes in comp2.

Basically I have click function in comp1 and I need the changes of on click on comp2.

```
comp1.ts
    isValue = false

    onclick(){
    this.service..isValue = true
    }

    comp2.ts
    isValue = false

    ngOnInIt(){
    this.isValue = true
    console.log(this.isValue) /// true

    then again turn this.isValue to false
    }
```

Here is the stackblitz link for behavior subject
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auuhng?file=app/two/two.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is working as described, but you are always setting the value to `true` (test-service.service.ts line 15: `this.isAdmins.next(true);`) so you don't see any change from subsequent clicks. If you are wanting to toggle the true/false state on subsequent clicks, you could do the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class TestServiceService {

  curValue: boolean = false;
  public isAdmins = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.curValue);
  cast = this.isAdmins.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeAdmin() {
    // toggle true/false:
    this.curValue = ! this.curValue;
    this.isAdmins.next(this.curValue);
  }

}
```